# Is typeof a function in C#?

Tags: c#

As you can see,it receive a class name as its param and return the type of the class.So why it's not a FUNCTION?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZOcY.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to Zoran's answer:

From a language grammar perspective, `typeof` cannot be implemented as a function, as its parameter is a type name **as a bare word**.

C# doesn't let you pass type names as parameters. So instead of having `typeof(string)` you'd have to call something like `typeof("System.String, mscorlib")`, which would defeat the operator's purpose since the `Type.GetType` function does exactly that.

`nameof` has the exact same issue.

Answer (score 6):

`typeof` is operator and it is processed by the compiler. When it comes to run time, `typeof` is not *invoked*, and therefore it is not a function.

In places where `typeof(T)` appears in code, compiler supplies reference to a `Type` object it has constructed for the type `T`.

Every type in your code has an associated `Type` object which you can fetch. There are two ways to fetch `Type` objects: `Object.GetType()` instance-level method, and `typeof` operator.